# adding additional parameters to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the function which adds a class to a div based on window position.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scroll >= 300) {
    $("#s-nav").addClass('s-nav-w');
  } else {
    $("#s-nav").removeClass('s-nav-w');
  }
});
```

I want to add another class to add/remove. I want to add `text-w` to `.main-nav li a` class.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: I added extra else commands apparently since the given answer works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will solve your issue

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 300) {
         $("#s-nav").addClass('s-nav-w');
         $(".main-nav li a").addClass('text-w');
    } else{
         $("#s-nav").removeClass('s-nav-w');
         $(".main-nav li a").removeClass('text-w');
    }
 });
```